# Prevent jQuery slideUp jump with margins

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an overlay that is set via

```
top:50%
left:50%
```

and calculated `margin-top` and `margin-left` to position it in the middle of the screen.

I want to slide it up to get rid of it, but it starts going crazy because of the margins.

Check out this fiddle that has the same results. What can I do? I can't really get rid of the margins unless there's a better way to position something perfectly in the middle of the screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/edjrdy61/1/

Comment: Will it always have defined width and height like it has in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent jump with margin, you must force the margin since jquery `slideUp()` change the margin at runtime.

Try this:

```
.foo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    margin-top:100px !important;
}
```

But if you want to get the better way to align middle-center of the screen, use absolute or fixed position. Example:

```
.foo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot believe how well the translate works!

Answer (score 0):

You're not wanting a margin here, you want the position set. This is a fixed element on the screen based on what you've described. As such, you should make it fixed.

Change the CSS to something like this:

```
.foo {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc3npb54/).